# Maven profile command -P not working with activeByDefault in pom.xml

Tags: maven, profile

I'm having issue with mvn clean package -Pprod command, after executing the command the property remains "spring.profiles.active=@spring.profiles.active@" in the application.properties file.

It only works if i define the activeByDefault in POM and executing mvn clean package without profile command. property is successfully updated to "spring.profiles.active=prod"

I want to selectively active the profile through the command line, instead of defining in the pom.

### GITHUB REPO

https://github.com/rennyong/demo

### UPDATE

If I remove jpamodelgen from dependencies and annotationproccessorpath and clean package, the application.properties will have the correct value.

### --NOT WORKING--

mvn clean package -Pprod

The following profiles are active:

- prod (source: :0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>prod</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

RESULT:

"spring.profiles.active=@spring.profiles.active@"

### -- WORKING --

mvn clean package

The following profiles are active:

- prod (source: :0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>prod</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

RESULT:

"spring.profiles.active=prod"

### POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- File Download-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Metamodel Generator
        Auto generation of meta model for specifications-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.29.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--Mapping Dto-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> -->
        <!-- Auto Generation of getter/setter and constructor-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.18</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>show-profiles</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>active-profiles</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <!-- This is needed when using Lombok 1.18.16 and above -->
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                            <version>5.4.29.Final</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>prod</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>      
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: I think there is something else going on. Your first example works for me (using the defaults from start.spring.io). Can you run "mvn help:active-profiles package" to see is some other profile from a parent or settings.xml has some effect? or if your IDE copies the .properties file skipping maven?

Comment: @wemu I did run with help:active-profiles. as shown in original post.The following "profiles are active:

prod (source: :0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)"

Comment: I just realise it does not work properly with clean command. why is this happening?

Comment: is the IDE also open or are you just using the command line?

Comment: I’m using command line in vs code. It works if I just package without clean command. Strange

Comment: I think more context about how `application.properties` is created. With maven-resources-plugin? Adding the full pom.xml will help to understand it

Comment: I would try on command line only. And you could also set a default property to see if the profile works or something else happened. I still think some other mechanism copies the file as well. That is usually a settings issue. But first: identify what is going on with the maven cli only. Close the other tools.

Comment: @polypiel application.properties file is first generated when u create a new project with spring project initialiser

Comment: @wemu
You are right. After some meddling with the code, I realise maven resources plugin runs(which filter and copy the correct properties file) runs before maven complier plugin.(complier plugin overwrite the properties file again)
Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Included Pom.

Update:

If I remove jpamodelgen from dependencies and annotationproccessorpath and clean package, the application.properties will have the correct value.

Comment: I'd say that Spring manages that own their own, I'd try this https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#using-overriding-command-line instead of configuring Maven profiles

Comment: Is that really the pom you are working with? because it works for me even with the jpamodelgen still added. I don't see why the compiler plugin would do anything with the properties file or the jpamodelgen. Something is still weird :/

Comment: @wemu it will start to fail to work properly when there are entity files, where jpamodelgen kicks in to generate meta model files.

Comment: A special entity? I've added a simple one and can see the Entity_.class generated. The filtering based on the profile still works. Can you create an example project on github? Have you checked your settings.xml files if there is something in there that may interferes?

Comment: I have setup a demo project with the same pom.xml. github.com/rennyong/demo if you open the property file when the mvn command is running you will see the following pattern. file deleted -> spring.profiles.active=prod -> spring.profiles.active=@spring.profiles.active@ with the following command: mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Pprod